# Fastest Ways to Upload thousand image to WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

what is the fast and best way to upload thousands of images (50k) to WordPress, and register it to the Media Section

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: ADD FROM SERVER plugin, can handle tens or hundreds of images, but it's too slow

Comment: The fastest way is _probably_ to manually somehow get all of the images to the server, maybe using FTP, then do "something". Personally I would write a custom [WP CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) command to do this.